# What is a UML business goal? What is its specific purpose? Distinguish it from the business use-case and locate it in the decisions level model

Tags: uml, business-process-management

What is a Unified Modeling Language business goal? What is its specific purpose? Distinguish it from the business use-case and locate it in the decisions level model.

Comment: There is no "Business Goal" element in UML.

Comment: Although I gave an answer to your question it's not a good idea to just post test questions here to be answered by someone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is simply a copy paste of a test question, without showing any effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a business goal in UML. UML is a language which can be used for many purposes. Even BPMN (which is for purely business application) does not have such an element. A business goal is an abstract thing and you can interpret it as you like (or better as it makes sense).

Also UML does does not define business use cases. This is also on another (business) layer.

And who (except your professor) knows what a decision level model is?